# Does PHP script abort when client disconnects?

Tags: php, readfile, fread, seek

I developed a web app content platform which allows users to search and download (big) video files. They can also watch the file directly in the browser. To do some access management, I'm not pointing them directly to the mp4/webm files, instead using a PHP script to handle this. My code is mostly based on the example found on http://www.media-division.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/

Snippet:

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    fseek($file, $seek_start);

    while(!feof($file)) 
    {
        print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) 
        {
            @fclose($file);
            exit;
        }           
    }
```

It basically sets the execution time to unlimited (large files), reads the file sequentially and pushes it to the client. My question is: does the script abort when the client aborts the download? For example, when there streaming a video using the HTML5 video player and stop watching.

ignore_user_abort is disabled by default, and I did not enable this in my configuration. But the line connection_status() function checks whether the connection is alive, and aborts the script if this is not the case (I guess).

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP but rather the way that PHP is invoked (i.e. probably the webserver, in your case). PHP itself can run for hours without any problem.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: You should write this as an answer and accept it

Comment: You can ping to user via ajax and if no respond set  connection_status=0

Comment: The browser still hangs, and Chrome displays 'Waiting for available socket'. Could it mean that connections are left open nevertheless? When I open the app with another browser, it loads instantly.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php):

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an
>   attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an
>   echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see
>   flush().

So I would say, as soon as the user has aborted, and you call this two lines:

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

The script will be stopped. I don't think that this part will be executed:

```
if (connection_status()!=0) 
{
    @fclose($file);
    exit;
}
```

Have you checked it? Is there a reason, why you could assume it is not?

You can simple write a Log File to confirm, if you're not able to see the current processes (Shared Hosting)